# Save separate attribute values using Relation reference in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.10

I have a list with different possible (allowed) combinations of different attributes (values) in a csv-file.
For example vegetation.csv

```
Number;Letter;Code;Bush;Soil;Tree
1;a;1a;k;x;f
1;a;1a;k;y;
1;a;1a;l;v;g
1;b;1b;;p;h
1;b;1b;m;q;h
1;b;1b;m;r;
2;a;2a;s;;f
2;b;2b;;x;
2;c;2c;;l;h
2;d;2d;k;;h
2;d;2d;k;v;g
2;e;2e;w;s;f
3;a;3a;b;;g
4;a;4a;b;v;h
```

I manage to get "depending" combo boxes by using project relations and the Relation reference widget with filters and chain filters: If I choose Number = 1, I may choose Letter a or b. If I choose b, I may set Bush to empty or m. If m, I can set Soil to q or r. If r, Tree is set to empty.

I need to save 4 attributes: Code, Bush, Soil and Tree.
so far I only succeed in saving Code (since Code is the referred field in the Project relation setup).
Is it somehow possible to save all the 4 attributes "in one operation"?

I may create more project relations, but then I will have to repeat the combo boxes 4 times (one time for each attribute I want to store)? I want the user to only once chose the combination of Number, Letter, Bush, Soil and Tree, and that these choses are saved into the 4 attributes Code, Bush, Soil and Tree.

Is this achievable?